# Python IDLE Shell random.randrange generated same number twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I generated same numbers successively, two times using random.randrange using Python IDLE Shell. I know that probability of this increase if I try this too many times. But I just started to try it with first line which generates the output 97, and I generated the same numbers in 3-4. lines. Same happened a few lines below them.

[image]

How can this happen?

Comment: That's completely normal. Human intuition for probability sucks.

Comment: It can happen because it's [pseudo] random

Comment: @JCaesar from "Starting Out with Python 3rd Edition" book: "When the random module is imported, it retrieves the system time from the computer’s internal clock and uses that as the seed value. The system time is an integer that represents the current date and time, down to a hundredth of a second."
I was not able to execute two lines in a hundredth of a second, therefore I think it's not about being pseudorandom.

Comment: It is not random but it is pseudo-random. For a better approach to random numbers in Python consider https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/secrets.html. Of course, even with the best random number generator such as that used by ERNIE here in the UK, you could still get the same number appear twice in succession. And that's because the generated numbers are **random**

Comment: it's completely random. See the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: @JCaesar I was not saying that it's not pseudo-random. I was just saying that the reason of the same number appear twice in succession is not being pseudo-random in my case. Yes, I know it is possible to get the same number, but I was just implying that it's probability is low in my case. But it seems like there is no explanation except coincidence. Thanks for reply and additional reading resource by the way!

Comment: @Bharel I knew birthday paradox, but since there is "being successive" in my case, I thought probability of my case is very low. But it seems like it's still random. Thanks!

Comment: Python doesn't use the system time for the default seed any more, but even if it did, that wouldn't have anything to do with what you're seeing. The seed is used to *initialize* the RNG. The RNG doesn't fetch a new seed for every `randrange` call.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I forgot. Seed is about series, not about every call, thanks.